# Prove the generating function $\sum_{N \geq 0} {M+N \choose N}x^{N} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{M+1}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

How do I prove the generating function  $1, (M+1), {M+2\choose 2}, {M+3 \choose 3}, \dots , {M+N \choose N}, \dots = \sum_{N \geq 0} {M+N \choose N}x^{N} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{M+1}}$

I can prove it for specific values of M, because I see a pattern:
$M=1$:
$$\quad\quad1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+6x^5+\dots=\frac{1}{(1−x)^2}$$
after taking derivative, it gives me the series for $M=2$:
$$1+3x+6x^2+10x^3+15x^4+21x^5+\dots=\frac{1}{(1−x)^3}$$
taking derivative again:
$$1+4x+10x^2+20x^3+35x^4+\dots=\frac{1}{(1−x)^4}$$
which is the series for $M=3$…how do I go from here to proving it for any $M\in\mathbb{N}$? Approaching this way seems like would lead to mathematical induction...do I use that somehow?

Comment: If you know how to prove it for specific values of $M$, then it seems like you are implicitly doing induction?

Comment: Start with $M=1$ and apply $d/dx.$

Comment: I see a pattern. but still, how do I prove it? mathematical induction?
$$ M=1: 1 +2x +3x^2 +4x^3 +5x^4+6x^5+ ... = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} $$
after taking derivative, it gives me the series for M=2:
$$1+3x + 6x^2 + 10x^3 + 15x^4 + 21x^5 + ... = \frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$$
taking derivative again:
$$1+4x + 10x^2 + 20x^3 + 35x^4 + ... = \frac{1}{(1-x)^4}$$ which is the series for M=3
.
.
.
how do I go from here to proving it for any $M \in \mathbb{N}$
Approaching this way seems like would lead to mathematical induction...

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it by induction.

$$P(k): \frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{m+i}{i}x^i$$

$P(0)$ is true, so we have $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty x^i$.

Assume $P(n)$ is true, and multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+2}} = \left(\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty x^j\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{m+i}{i}x^i\right)$$

$i$ and $j$ are independent, so the sums can be nested.

$$= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{m+i}{i}\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty x^{i+j}$$

Let $i+j=k$. Note that this is a different $j$ from the previous equation, and because $i\ge0$, the new $j$ is capped at $k$.

$$= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{j=0}^k\binom{m+k-j}{k-j} x^k$$

By the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) and the independence of $j$, the inner sum can be re-written.

$$= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{m+1+k}{k} x^k$$

Comment: Aren't we supposed to get at the end $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} {m+1+i \choose i}x^i$ i.e. $i$ instead of $k$?

Can you please explain how you applied the hockey-stick identity?

Comment: @Emmaka; the index letter doesn't matter. $\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\binom{m+k-j}{k-j}$ from the second last line gives the identity as per the link. If the denominator in a binomial is $<0$, the binomial is $0$, so the infinite sum is capped.

Comment: In the inner sum, $j$ should go from $0$ to $k$.

Comment: @martycohen; fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also obtain the generating function directly via stars-and-bars.  Fix $M$, and let $a_N$ be the number of nonnegative integer solutions of
$$y_1+\dots+y_{M+1}=N.$$
Then $$a_N=\binom{(M+1)+N-1}{(M+1)-1}=\binom{M+N}{M}=\binom{M+N}{N}.$$
So
$$
\sum_{N=0}^\infty \binom{M+N}{N} x^N
=\sum_{N=0}^\infty a_N x^N
=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\right)^{M+1}
=\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{M+1}
=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{M+1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also prove it
starting with the
generalized binomial theorem
(which some might consider cheating):

$(1+x)^a
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n}x^n
$
where
$\binom{a}{n}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(a-k)}{n!}
$.

$\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{M+1}}
=(1-x)^{-M-1}
$
so we want

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{-M-1}{n}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(-M-1-k)}{n!}\\
&=(-1)^n\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(M+1+k)}{n!}\\
&=(-1)^n\dfrac{\prod_{k=M+1}^{M+n}k}{n!}\\
&=(-1)^n\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{M+n}k}{n!\prod_{k=1}^{M}k}\\
&=(-1)^n\dfrac{(M+n)!}{n!M!}\\
&=(-1)^n\binom{M+n}{n}\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{M+1}}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-M-1}{n}(-x)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{M+n}{n}(-1)^nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{M+n}{n}x^n\\
\end{array}
$