# Extract Coefficients to Solve Recurrence Relation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I'm having difficulty moving from the generating function, $h(x)$, expressed in the form of partial fractions (which I believe I've successfully found) to the closed form of the recurrence relation, $e_n$.

The recurrence relation is:
$e_0=e_1=1, e_2=2$, and $e_n=3e_{n-1}-3e_{n-2}+e_{n-3}$.

I have calculated the generating function, $h(x)$, as:
$h(x)=\frac{1-2x+2x^2}{1-3x+3x^2-x^3}$.

Applying partial fractions, obtain:
$h(x)=\frac{2}{1-x}+\frac{2}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$.

From Wolfram, I know that $e_n=\frac{1}{2}(n^2-n+2)$, but I can't see how the coefficients of $x_n$ are extracted from the terms to arrive at this solution (with the exception of the first term of the partial fraction, which clearly becomes $2$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generating function to apply here is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{m+n}{n}x^n = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}},$$
which has several recent proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394123/prove-the-generating-function-sum-n-geq-0-mn-choose-nxn-frac1).

The $m=0$ case is the one you already knew.  Now use the $m=1$ and $m=2$ cases.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)' = \frac1{(1-x)^2}$$

and

$$\left( \frac1{(1-x)^2} \right)' = \frac2{(1-x)^3}$$

Comment: I see the point you're making but I'm not sure how to apply this fact to solve?

Comment: This makes sense to me now! In effect, we shift the power series given by $\frac{1}{1-x}$ by one degree each time we take the derivative. So, for $\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$, we've shifted the power series by two degrees. The OGFs for each series follow directly from this observation. Thanks for helping me connect the dots!